# Adding New Account

Tags: ledger, error, account, tezbox

I have just linked my Ledger to my Tezbox wallet and funded it with about 10XTZ. I can see the transaction in TzScan and the amount is shown in the Main Account in the Tezbox wallet. But when I try to add a new Account, as the first step to delegating my Tezos I get "Uh-oh There was an error adding account. Please ensure that your Main Account has funds available.

Please advise how I can add a new account.

Comment: What version of TezBox are you using? The webwallet?

Comment: Yes - the web wallet.